# How to name and implement Result set rows in DDD?

Tags: php, pdo, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

In DDD you have an entity with an unique identifier (ID or UUID). Usually a entity represents a storable row in a database table. My repository can load a single entity (findById) or all Entities at once (findAll).

But now a have to write a special and very complex query with joins to other tables. The result set is not a special (User) entity anymore because I have selected different fields from multiple tables with aliases and so on. Depending on the query, the result may not contain an id.

I've hydrated this rows successfully into into an new collection of objects but struggling with the name (and type) of that thing.

My question is:

How to name and categorize such kind of rows coming from a custom query in DDD?

Comment: Hence the name "domain-driven" in DDD name. How to name things - get to your domain people and ask them, what is it you just queried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need a query service here.

DDD fits really nicely with CQRS, and I believe the results you want are read-only.

In this case you create a special object for your need: UserData, if the user contains some other relations like a collection of roles, or right, you can call it UserRightsData for instance, and fetch it from a UserQueryService.

Query services are typically in the application layer.

If you want non read-only results, and instead plain entities that you can manipulate and persist, then you need to give us more details. In particular, you should be able to load this entity from a repository, call a domain operation, and persist it, via an application service.

Query services are well suited for views, tables, and data display, with sorting, filtering and so on...

Edit: plalx nailed it in a response of Eben Roux's post.

```
ProjectName/
    IdentityAndAccess/
        Application/
            Command/
                AuthenticateUserCommand.php
                ChangeEmailAddressCommand.php
                ChangeUserPasswordCommand.php
                ChangeUserPersonalNameCommand.php
                ...
            Data/
                UserData.php
                UserRightsData.php (POPO containing User infos and a list of rights)
                RightData.php (Single comment infos)
            UserApplicationService.php
            UserQueryService.php
        Domain/
            Model/
```

Comment: Thanks. So I should use a "query service" (application layer) which returns a "read model" (DTO). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, and your read model is adapted to a view you want to fill in.

The beauty of this is that you only render what is needed, e.g. if you don't need database ID, but instead a domain key, you don't need to fetch the database ID.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should avoid querying your domain model unless you are truly after a specific aggregate.  Even then, and depending on your design, you may not be able to get the required data.

The typical recommendation is to use a specialized query layer along with, possibly, a **read model** that represents the required data.  That read model may be as typed or loose as you need.  For instance, if a list of name/value pairs will do the trick perhaps you may opt for *that*.

These queries are not really part of the domain and, as such, fall outside of the domain-driven design in terms of modelling.  They are, however, important as part of your overall architecture/approach.

**update**:

In response to @Luca Masera's comment:

I typically use something like this (C#) for, say, a `Product`:

```
public interface IProductQuery
{
    int ActiveCount();
    DataRow Details(Guid id);
    Query.Product Get(Guid id);
    IEnumerable<Query.Product> Matching(ProductSpecification specification);
}
```

The `Query` namespacing is so that the read model `Product` does not interfere with my actual domain `Product`.

Depending on my requirement I will use the appropriate return object/structure/type.

Comment: So, for example, you could hide away all this "extra domain requests" in an interface. Then, in the infrastructure layer, you implement this in the way you think is better. As a consequence of this you keep your model clean and all the extra stuff (not really part of the domain but required to satisfy your business process) is kept away from the model and could adapt to the infrastructure you use (later this data could be indexed and queried with Solr).

Comment: Are your specifications defined in the domain or only in the query layer? If in the latter then what is the benefit compared to a simpler approach such as having dedicated query methods for every queries? For queries I usually do not have a generic data holder and every query operation returns a different kind of DTO, rendering a `Matching` operation a bit less useful. E.g. `DashboardData data = queryService.dashboardDataForUser(userId)`. It's also much easier to optimize queries that way.

Comment: I've used specifications for security rules though, where a specification could further constrain a query by translating a rule to SQL (visitor pattern), but also constrain a command, allowing me only return AR instances that users could act upon without code duplication.

Comment: You could certainly have dedicated queries but sometimes you may have a couple of criterion that a user may, for instance, fill in on a form.  But you could *still* get away with having your data access query ignore certain "empty" or `null` values.  I find specifications most useful when I actually build a dynamic query vs passing in parameters.

Comment: @EbenRoux Thanks. So I should use a "query service" (application layer) which returns a "read model" (DTO). Is this correct?

Comment: TBH I don't quite know where it fits ito of layering.  It is a concern in and of itself and can be surface in an integration layer such as an application layer.  You may even have an API that may be used by something closer to your DB.  It is up to you where it fits in.  The main idea is that it exposes data in at a more "raw" level and it is optomised for querying/reading.